# Busqueda Secuencial de tipo generico

Tags: java

estoy trabajando en una busqueda secuencial de tipo generico pero tengo problemas a la hora de definir mis comparables

```
 public class Buscador_secuencial<E extends Comparable<E>> {
                  private E[] b;
               public Buscador_secuencial(E [] palabras){
                           b = palabras;
               }
               public int buscar(Comparable<E> v) {
               int posicion = -1;
               for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){//recorremos todo el arreglo
                  if(b[i] == dato){//comparamos el elemento en el arreglo con el buscado
                posicion = i;//Si es verdadero guardamos la posicion
                break;//Para el ciclo
               }
             }
             return posicion;
            }
            }


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español! Por favor, puede explicarnos en detalle, cual parte especifica de 'definir mis comparables' que tiene duda? Y qué quiere conseguir?  Si se devuelve mensajes de error, por favor los publica tambien. Una pregunta con informacion mas completa tiene mejor probabilidad para obtener respuestas.

Comment: ¿Dónde defines `dato`? Tienes: `if(b[i] == dato)`. ¿No debería ser `if(b[i] == v)`? Revisa eso. Saludos